# Difference between >>= and concatMap

Tags: haskell, monads

I was playing around with `>>=` today, trying to understand monads, and found an interesting pattern. When working with the list monad, `>>=` seemed to behave like concatMap. I searched around to try to find any similarity, looking specifically in the definitions on hackage.

Some things I tried:

`[1, 2, 3] >>= (iter 5 id) => [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3]`

```
concatMap (iter 5 id) [1, 2, 3]=> [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3]
```

`[1, 2, 3] >>= (iter 5 (+5)) => [1,6,11,16,21,2,7,12,17,22,3,8,13,18,23]`

`concatMap (iter 5 (+5) ) [1, 2, 3] => [1,6,11,16,21,2,7,12,17,22,3,8,13,18,23]`

`iter` is just non-infinite iterate,

```
iter i f a = toL $ Data.Sequence.iterateN i f a
  where
    toL = Data.Foldable.toList :: Data.Sequence.Seq a -> [a]
```

(working in repl.it so the imports are screwed up).

Is `(>>=)` equivalent to `concatMap` for lists?
Is it the generalization of `concatMap`?

Comment: See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Understanding_monads/List for an in-depth explanation of the implementation of Monad for the list type.  Also https://wiki.haskell.org/All_About_Monads#List_is_also_a_monad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, `(=<<)` is `concatMap` for lists. `>>=` is just a combination of `fmap` and `join` (the generalization of `concat`) for any Monad, so this makes intuitive sense as well.

Comment: Thanks for the bit about join, I never really realized that!

Comment: `xs >>= f = join $ fmap f xs`

Answer (score 9):

Yes, with the arguments flipped. Comparing these type signatures should bring out the similarity, though the special list syntax interferes:

```
Prelude> :t flip concatMap
flip concatMap :: Foldable t => t a -> (a -> [b]) -> [b]
Prelude> :t (>>=)
(>>=)          :: Monad m    => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

Comment: It’s legal to write the list type constructor in prefix form (`Foldable t => t a -> (a -> [] b) -> [] b`), it’s just that nobody does because it leads to more parentheses (`[] ([] a)` vs. `[[a]]`).